# Replace all string of existing xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to replace the existing .xml extension file's inside text with String.

Why I'm doing this is: I wanted to read images from .xml file. But image did not loading file from the existing folder of .xml file. I tried so many times to solve this problem. And only possible thing was the put the hard path of the Image file destination. So then I started to try this:

1. read the .xml file's inside string - Solved
2. get the full parent of the xml path - Solved
3. read text inside xml and export to string - Solved
4. find "`<img src='`" existed area from string - Solved
5. put the Parent path after existed area - Solved
6. save string to existing .xml by replacing all string - Unsolved?

Purpose of the work is "Show images from XML file". So please someone answer unsolved article.
And don't suggest me about methods like Base64ToImage. I just want to go like this way. Hope I will have my answer here.

existing XML: 
`<helpRoot>
    <body Type="Section1">
      <![CDATA[
    <img src='Help1.png'/>

    <h3 style="color:#2B94EA;font-family:open sans;">Section1</h3></hr>

    <p style="color:#484848;font-family:open sans;">Text is shown</p>
    <h3 style="color:#3399FF;font-family:open sans;"> Image is not showing</h3></hr>

    ]]></body>
    <body Type="Section2">
      <![CDATA[
    <img src='Help2.png'/>

    <h3 style="color:#2B94EA;font-family:open sans;">Section2</h3></hr>

    <p style="color:#484848;font-family:open sans;">Text is shown</p>
    <h3 style="color:#3399FF;font-family:open sans;"> Image is not showing</h3></hr>

    ]]></body>
    ...
</helpRoot>`

new XML string:
`<helpRoot>
    <body Type="Section1">
      <![CDATA[
    <img src='D:/Project/Image/Help1.png'/>

    <h3 style="color:#2B94EA;font-family:open sans;">Section1</h3></hr>

    <p style="color:#484848;font-family:open sans;">Text has showing</p>
    <h3 style="color:#3399FF;font-family:open sans;"> Image is showing</h3></hr>

    ]]></body>
    <body Type="Section2">
      <![CDATA[
    <img src='D:/Project/Image/Help2.png'/>

    <h3 style="color:#2B94EA;font-family:open sans;">Section2</h3></hr>

    <p style="color:#484848;font-family:open sans;">Text has shown</p>
    <h3 style="color:#3399FF;font-family:open sans;"> Image is not showing</h3></hr>

    ]]></body>
    ...
</helpRoot>`

Comment: Your question is very confusing. If you mean you want to manipulate XML files, it would really help if you'd show a sample input and desired output. I would strongly suggest that you *don't* use string replacement here. Manipulate it *as* XML with an XML API.

Comment: Do you only have issue with saving the newly formed xml file as in 5th point you already added the string to xml successfully?

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to save my "Prepared" string instead of the text inside the .xml file and show results .

Comment: @mangasm Does my answer below help? I tried as best I could with the information you gave above.

Comment: Looks like *Find 10 differences puzzle*

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `XDocument` and `HTMLAgilityPack`

```
var xml =
@"<base>
    <child><![CDATA[<img src=""/path"" />]]></child>
</base>";

var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var xChild = xDocument.Descendants("child").First();

var cData = xChild.Nodes().OfType<XCData>().First();

var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

htmlDocument.LoadHtml(cData.Value);

var imgNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("img");

imgNode.Attributes["src"].Value = "/new/path";

using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    htmlDocument.Save(writer);
    cData.Value = writer.ToString();
}
```

`xDocument` now contains:

```
<base>
  <child><![CDATA[<img src="/new/path">]]></child>
</base>
```

Comment: Yes, for handling XML I would go with `XDocument` as well. But from your question I am not sure what your problem is exactly.

Comment: Thanks @dav_i for your contribution. But my XML file contains so many CDATA. And there are so many <img> tags inside all CDATA. So then I just wanted to replace existing XML content with my processed XML string. Any other suggestions :)

Comment: @mangasm Use the above without all the HTMLAgility stuff, check my [previous revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19444863/1)